# How to test sync adapter running

Tags: android, synchronization, android-syncadapter

Following this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html), I managed to set up a sync adapter to do data sync between Android app and web server. I can see the sync working when I force the app to do sync by toggle the Sync on/off from Settings > Accounts > MyApp.

But, I have not been able to confirm that the sync is actually working when internet connection is available after the app running without internet connection.

I chose to run the sync adapter after a network message:

```
mResolver.setSyncAutomatically(ACCOUNT, AUTHORITY, true);
```

How do I test to make sure that sync adapter running after a network message? Should manually turning off/on internet connection (3G and/or Wifi) trigger the sync adapter to run immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Once you call setSyncAutomatically with sync (3rd) parameter set to true , it calls your sync adapter immediately once. Then the next sync would happen anytime in next 24 hours. So to test if that sync gets called you switch off the Wifi/3G then change the date to next day and switch on the Wifi/3G. This should trigger the sync again.

Comment: Can you provide the source that it will sync again in the next 24 hours ?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger sync manually by calling (in example you provide) `SyncUtils.TriggerRefresh();`

Comment: Determine connectivity change like this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)  and add the code above for force sync.